# How to subscribe to getstream billing only for their chat features

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, stream, billing

Please how much does getstream charge for chat features only

I've sent them messages through their forum but I get no reply from them.

I've also messaged their sales team but bot always reply that my request has been received and that they will reply soon which they don't do.